# mysqli fetch_assoc() not posting

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code and the fetch_assoc is not working, when i manually put in the email address and hash it will post active='1' fine see code below any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once("db.php");

$hash = mysqli_real_escape_string($comm, $_POST["token"]);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($comm, $_POST["email"]);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND hash='$hash'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
     $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

     if ($row['active'] == '1') {
          echo 'You Have Already Activated Your Account';
     } else {
          $sql1 = "UPDATE users SET active='1' WHERE email='$email' AND hash='$hash'";

          // If i use the email address and the hash then it works
          // $sql1 = "UPDATE users SET active='1' WHERE email='email@mydomain.com' AND hash='28a78fea4088711fc7a2bb1a6abeb3aa'";

          if ($conn->query($sql1)) {
               $SESSION['userActivated'] = true;
               header("Location: login.php");
               exit();
          }
     }
} else {
     echo 'Token Mismatch!';
}
```

Comment: turn on error reporting, ensure post values are populated, if not just terminate the script, no reason to run without them anyways

Comment: and since you're using mysqli, why not use prepared statements instead

Comment: var_dump($result) ?

Comment: I don't understand your code, sorry. You look into the DB and search for users with given Mail and Hash (SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND hash='$hash'). If there are no users ($result->num_rows == 0) then you look at the active flag of this (not existing) user (???). This will be false every time. Then you try to update this not existing user. This will also fail every time. Did I miss some point?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as below, it will work

```
<?php

 session_start();

 require_once("db.php");

 $hash = mysqli_real_escape_string($comm, $_POST["token"]);
 $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($comm, $_POST["email"]);

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND hash='$hash'";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);


 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

      $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

      if ($row['active'] == '1') {
       echo 'You Have Already Activated Your Account';
      } else {
            $sql1 = "UPDATE users SET active='1' WHERE email='$email' AND hash='$hash'";

           // If i use the email address and the hash then it works
           // $sql1 = "UPDATE users SET active='1' WHERE email='email@mydomain.com' AND hash='28a78fea4088711fc7a2bb1a6abeb3aa'";

           if ($conn->query($sql1)) {
                $SESSION['userActivated'] = true;
                header("Location: login.php");
                exit();
            }
      }
 } else {
      echo 'Token Mismatch!';
 }
```

?>

Comment: Can you highlight which steps are relevant to solving the problem?

Comment: the condition should be if ($result->num_rows > 0) {, this is the only change